# How to use text view value to query database row equal to the text view value?

Tags: android, database, text, view, row

I'm sure glad this site is here. It has helped me out every time.

So my new problem is, I have passed a value from one activity to another and set that value to a text view. The value is always numeric. I then use "on menu item selected" to pass that value to another activity and set that value to a text view. What I'm looking to do is use that value (which is numeric and represents the row id associated with the data) to query the database and return the row associated with the numeric value mentioned earlier. Then populate the appropriate edit text or text views of the same activity.

Here is where I call for the text value (tv1)

```
private void populateFields() {

if (tv1!=null) {
    Cursor note = mDbHelper.fetchRow(tv1);
    startManagingCursor(note);

    //rowid.setText(note.getString(
        //  note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DatabaseManager.KEY_ROWID)));
    txtbox28.setText(note.getString(
           note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DatabaseManager.KEY_NAME)));
    txtbox1.setText(note.getString(
            note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DatabaseManager.NICBASEML)));
    txtbox4.setText(note.getString(
            note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DatabaseManager.NICDROPS)));
    txtbox8.setText(note.getString(
            note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DatabaseManager.NICPERCT)));
```

and the query

```
public Cursor fetchRow(TextView tv1) throws SQLException {

            Cursor mCursor =

                mDb.query(true,DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME,
                        NICBASEML, NICDROPS, NICPERCT, PGML, PGDROPS,PGPERCT,
                        VGML,VGDROPS,VGPERCT, WAPML, WAPDROPS, WAPPERCT, 
                        FLV1NAME, FLV1ML, FLV1DROPS, FLV1PERCT,
                        FLV2NAME, FLV2ML, FLV2DROPS, FLV2PERCT,
                        FLV3NAME, FLV3ML, FLV3DROPS, FLV3PERCT,
                        FLV4NAME, FLV4ML, FLV4DROPS, FLV4PERCT,
                        DROPSML, AMOUNT, FINALNIC, BPG, BVG, BASENIC}, KEY_ROWID + "=" + tv1,  null, null, null, null, null);

            if (mCursor != null) {
                mCursor.moveToFirst();
            }
            return mCursor;

        }
```

this is the error I get now.

02-07 12:14:16.120: E/AndroidRuntime(2713): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "@405dcd48": syntax error: , while compiling: SELECT DISTINCT _id, name, nicbaseml, nicdrops, nicperct, pgml, pgdrops, pgperct, vgml, vgdrops, vgperct, wapml, wapdrops, wapperct, flv1name, flv1ml, flv1drops, flv1perct, flv2name, flv2ml, flv2drops, flv2perct, flv3name, flv3ml, flv3drops, flv3perct, flv4name, flv4ml, flv4drops, flv4perct, dropsml, amount, finalnic, bpg, bpg, basenic FROM recipes WHERE _id=android.widget.TextView@405dcd48

hmmm stuck on this one. Where is the error @405dcd48?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution. It took many hours (2 days) to figure this out and then it was a dhooo! hand to the face moment. But never the less, here is the solution for others that have the same issue. In your declaration for populating the fields (in this case fetch(row).

Do this:

```
private void populateFields() {

String row = tv1.getText().toString();//String to get the textview of the rowid

        if (tv1!= null) { //Checking to see if the field is not empty to proceed

            Cursor note = mDbHelper.fetchRow(row);//Calling my cursor to manage data
            startManagingCursor(note);//Starting the management and retrieve data
```

You will get the error as above and then a null pointer exception. This can be fixed by declaring your fields -->(txtbox1=  (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView22);.

Your database manager needs to be configured for a String.

Like this:

```
public Cursor fetchRow(String row) throws SQLException {
```

Now you can retrieve the data from the row using a textview or editview value equal to the row id of the data you are looking for.